# Failed to load native .so library in Android 9 Nokia 5 device

Tags: android

I am trying to load native library in Android 9 Nokia 5, but it fails. It works fine in Android 8 and other Android 9 devices like MI.

My code:

```
String libName = "xyz";
String libPath1 = "/data/data/com.android.package/lib/libxyz.so";
String libPath2 = "/system/lib/libxyz_rw.so";
if (new File(libPath1).exists()) {
    System.load(libPath1);
} else if (new File(libPath2).exists()) {
    System.load(libPath2);
} else{
    System.loadLibrary(libName);
}
```

Comment: Errorlog giving clues?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got the solution. I was having a REALM library in my code which was causing the problem. The workaround was to exclude the Realm’s ARM64 library from the APK file by adding the following code to the app’s build.gradle

```
android {
//...
packagingOptions {
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
}
//...
}
```

Here is the document https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started